# SetWindowPos using HWND_TOP does not have any effect

Tags: winapi, windows-10

In a specific case I would like to force the window of one of my own application to the top of Z order. This lead me to the Win32 API ::SetWindowPos(...).

To test this API I did as follow;

1. Started Notepad and MSPaint.
2. Made sure MSPaint window was in front of Notepad window.
3. Using ::GetTopWindow(..) and GetNextWindow(..) found all windows available in OS with their HWND and PID. Please ignore any shortcuts in this code, it is not production quality.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"

int main()
{
    int index = 0;
    for (HWND hwnd = ::GetTopWindow(NULL); hwnd != NULL; hwnd = ::GetNextWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT))
    {
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);

        char text[512] = { 0x00 };
        GetWindowTextA(hwnd, &text[0], 511);

        std::cout << "Windows [" << index << "] " << (int)hwnd << " " << pid << " " << text << std::endl;
        ++index;
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
Windows [81] 4983752 20828 DDE Server Window
Windows [82] 134148 20828 MSCTFIME UI
Windows [83] 854994 20828 Default IME
Windows [84] 462036 20828
Windows [85] 1838198 20828 bar - Paint
Windows [86] 1116688 20828
Windows [87] 265286 20828 GDI+ Window (mspaint.exe)
Windows [88] 265288 20828 Default IME
Windows [89] 721172 19016 MSCTFIME UI
```

4. Using SetWindowPos for each of the windows associated with notepad PID. The method returned 1 and GetLastError is 0 in all cases but the Notepad window did not change Z-order and was still hidden behind MSPaint window.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
    HWND current = HWND(atoi(argv[1]));
    bool res = ::SetWindowPos(current, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    std::cout << "Result:" << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notepad, MSPaint and applications in step 3 and 4 are executed by same user.
Applications in step 3 and 4 are executed in admin mode.

Using TOPMOST is not an option.

SetWindowPos documentation states "*As part of the Vista re-architecture, all services were moved off the interactive desktop into Session 0. **hwnd and window manager operations are only effective inside a session and cross-session attempts to manipulate the hwnd will fail**. For more information, see The Windows Vista Developer Story: Application Compatibility Cookbook.*". I am not sure what the mean by "session" in this context and the API does not really fail.

How am I using the SetWindowPos wrongly?

Appreciate any input :-)

Comment: You wanted to force a third-party window to the top of the Z order? Or you want to force one of your app's *own* windows to the top of the Z order? Can you post the *actual code* that you used? Your description in English is somewhat imprecise, particularly how you are iterating through and finding windows. I'm particularly unclear how you found a single instance of Notepad to have more than one top-level window... The SetWindowPos API *does* work; I and thousands of other developers have used it. (You are not cross-session here, based on your description.)

Comment: The Windows version matters.  On Win11, Notepad is no longer a normal Win32 app, so not a great choice to test this.  Calc.exe isn't either btw.

Comment: Notepad is not a normal Win32 app anymore? Oh boy, what other surprises await me in Windows 11...

Comment: Using Windows 10. Not sure about the build number but think its 19XXX something (cannot check now since I am at home)

Comment: I understand that the SetWindowPos method works and that I am doing something wrong. That is why I wrote this post.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with SetWindowPos(,HWND_TOPMOST,...) and then SetWindowPos(,HWND_NOTOPMOST,...).  (Windows 11)  
HWND_TOP has a lot of restrictions about being a foreground window, this doesn't (yet - someday they'll probably break this)  I also ran into a function 'BringWindowToTop' but I don't know if that will work.